# How can you make linear discriminant analysis reduce dimensions to the number of dimensions you are looking for?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

Let's say I have a $m \times n$ matrix where $m$ is the number of points and $n$ is the number of dimensions. I would like to give a target dimension parameter which is let's say d. d can be a set of values like $\{2,4,6,\ldots,n\}$. I would then approach the problem using Fisher's linear discriminant analysis to give me output matrix in $m \times d$. Is this possible to do? I still don't understand how LDA reduces dimensions from let's say 10,000 to 1,000.

Comment: LDA produces _min(n,c-1)_ discriminants (_c_ is the number of classes). They are sorted descendingly by their discriminative contribution. You may leave _d_ first discriminants, exactly like you leave first _d_ components in Principal Components analysis.

Comment: Please have a look at question http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43768/dimensionality-reduction-using-pca-with-svd-of-correlation-matrix/43772#43772 A good resource to learn more about LDA/LSI is Chapter 18 of freely available book [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/).

Comment: Please search `discriminant LDA dimensionality reduction` this site for relevant questions/answers.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni You might be confusing Latent Dirichlet Allocation (a probabilistic extension of Latent Semantic Indexing), with linear discriminant analysis, since they both use the acronym LDA. This question is about linear discriminant analysis, which is a very separate algorithm from latent dirichlet allocation / search indexing / topic modeling in general. The Manning Information Retrieval book does not appear to have any sections on linear discriminant analysis.

Answer (score 4):

How LDA does dimension reducion has same methodology with PCA. When you get **J(W)** at LDA (W is result that which minimizes within class scatter matrix but maximizes between class scatter matrix)

```
W = inv(Sw)*Sb
```

When you get **W**, you can get result with:

```
 V is eigenvectors of W
 final_result = V'*your_data
```

before that the trick plays role. As like at PCA, you can get eigenvectors and eigenvalues of **W** and you can discard some eigenvectors that has smallest corresponding eigenvalues. Then if you multiply your data with that eliminated eigenvector matrix (**V**) you get a lower dimension.